# Enable local history in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, history

After re-installation of NetBeans my local history doesn't work any more.

Can somebody tell me where I can activate the local history or where I have to make changes in the config file?

Comment: i would recommend you use **[local svn repository](http://thinkinging.com/2007/04/12/creating-a-local-subversion-repository-with-tortoisesvn/)** (or **git**) as its much more powerful, than local history.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the menu bar, choose `Tools`, then `Plugins`. Go to the `Installed` tab in the plugins window. Check the `Show details` box to get a full view and now search for the entry with name "Local History". Verify that it is set to active. If not, activate it.

Also, from the same `Tools` menu option, open `Options` and go to tab `Versioning`. Check the settings for "Local History". You can set there how long the history files should be kept.

Comment: The settings now seem to be under **Tools** > **Options** > The **Team** Section > **Versioning** tab > Then select **History** in the **Versioning Systems** list.

Comment: The settings now seem to be under Tools > Options > The Team Section > Versioning tab. From the list on the left (called "Versioning Systems"), select "General". From the "Versioning System" combobox, select "Local History". NetBeans 8.1

Comment: In Netbeans 8.2 it's as @user3902302 stated, except under the "Versioning Systems" list at left select "History" instead of "General".

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem where Local History stopped working after upgrade from 7.1 to 7.2. This happened on 2 computers, both running Kubuntu 12.04 and OpenJDK 7.

Versioning options, as described in other answer, were available, but didn't help - it still wasn't recording history.

Reinstalling Local History plugin also didn't work.

What finally did make it work again was uninstall of **all** versioning plugins (CVS, Git, Mercurial, Local History,...), restarting the IDE, then installing only Local History, and restarting again. Can't say would it help in case you need some other versioning system enabled again.

Spent a lot of time searching for a way to fix this. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had a bit of trouble finding the context menu that included the link through to local history.

If you right click on the file in the projects window (the directory/files tree), then click History > Show history it will give you the full history of the file including the local history.

The I noticed that the history view is also accessible from the top of the Netbeans file editor panel, just beneath the file tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching the History.

[image]

I was able to find it here: `View -> Show Editor Toolbar`

[image]